# ubuntu 15.10 default editor for sftp remote files doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, sftp

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64bit and trying to open a remote file (sftp) with sublimetext2.

All worked fine till yesterday.

Today all files listed in a remote sftp directory are opened with gedit, despite the default program to open these files (.php, .txt, etc) is set up to sublimetext2.

Also, in the "file properties" -> "Open with" there is already set up to default sublimetext2.

Opening this way still use gedit instead:
right click on file -> open with other application -> select sublimetext2 (already set as default).

I already tried with leafpad but the result is exactly the same.

**Edit:**

I tried this:
- opened sublime from terminal with " > fileName.log" to force it write some log in the terminal.
- made a new file from sublime-text and then save it to the remote location. When pressing Ok to save the file, after some seconds the editor crashes.
In the terminal appears:

```
(sublime_text:3228): Gtk-WARNING **: Operazione non supportata dal backend
(sublime_text:3228): Gtk-WARNING **: Operazione non supportata dal backend
/usr/bin/sublime-text: riga 3:  3228 Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
/opt/sublime_text_2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

In the /var/crash/ appeared the file "_opt_sublime_text_2_sublime_text.1000.crash", an excerpt is:

```
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0x7fab2f9b66fa <strlen+42>:  movdqu (%rax),%xmm12
 PC (0x7fab2f9b66fa) ok
 source "(%rax)" (0x00000000) not located in a known VMA region (needed readable region)!
 destination "%xmm12" ok
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA
Stacktrace:
```

**Edit: crash log of Sublime text 3**

```
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0x7fa347c126fa <strlen+42>:  movdqu (%rax),%xmm12
 PC (0x7fa347c126fa) ok
 source "(%rax)" (0x00000000) not located in a known VMA region (needed readable region)!
 destination "%xmm12" ok
SegvReason: reading NULL VMA
SourcePackage: sublime-text
Stacktrace:
 #0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
 No locals.
 #1  0x000000000074c324 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #2  0x00000000005c5ffe in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #3  0x000000000044c0eb in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #4  0x000000000044c7b8 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #5  0x000000000044c904 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #6  0x000000000057e3c6 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #7  0x000000000058e640 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #8  0x000000000058723c in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #9  0x00000000005af5fc in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #10 0x00000000005c3924 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #11 0x00000000005c8747 in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
 #12 0x00007fa3426cbe5c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
 No symbol table info available.
 [...]
 sublime_text crashed with SIGSEGV in strlen()
```

What I must do to solve that frustrating problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened yesterday? Computers don't just "randomly" change their settings.

Comment: nothing happened yesterday. Today ubuntu seggested to update lightdm, and then (I presume) after updating it, the issue happened.

Comment: Well, I *strongly* suggest updating to [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3) using the `.deb` format (install with `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`). Then, follow my instructions on making Sublime the default text editor [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/396938/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-3-the-default-text-editor/397387#397387) on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: I'm already doing the istructions you tell in that post. My sublime version (2) is present in /usr/share/applications/ but as sublime-text-2.desktop. It's a problem?

Comment: Anyway, the problem occurs also with any other editor different from gedit

Comment: If your update today also updated `gedit`, you'll need to edit `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` again. And, like I mentioned earlier, I'd *really* strongly suggest you update to ST3. In addition to all of the bug fixes, new features, and access to the large and growing number of plugins that only support ST3, the `.deb` is installed like any other Ubuntu program and can help protect against issues like this.

Comment: Also with ST3 doesn't work. It crashes when i save in the remote location.

Comment: Your edit shows crash data from ST2. What about ST3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution founded in the italian Ubuntu-it forum:
http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=607760

The solution is to use **sshfs**.